# Python - Importing all file names from one program (dir.py) to another program (pj.py). But the file names stored in the directory is listed twice

Tags: python-2.7

Importing all file names from one program (dir.py) to another program (pj.py). But the file names passed from dir.py to pj.py is twice instead of once.

Here's the dir.py program-

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
root = 'C:/Users/Desktop/Files/test' ##THE PATH IS WHERE ALL EXCEL DATASHEETS ARE STORED. 
# Traverse directory, and list files
for files in os.listdir(root):
    #Call the main python program
    file_location = os.path.join(root, files)
    print files
    execfile('C:/Users/Desktop/pj.py')

#THIS PATH REFERS TO THE DIRECTORY WHERE THE PYTHON PROGRAM pj.py is going to manipulate the datasheet. It takes the file name from dir.py as a parameter.
```

Now, in the pj.py program-

```
import xlrd
import re
from dir import file_location

#The file location is passed as a argument from first program. Worksheet is open
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_location)
```

When I print it, it shows me the following:

```
['Disambiguation_Version 1t_Bo Zheng.xlsx', 'Disambiguation_Version 1t_Jun Xi.xlsx', 'Disambiguation_Version 1_Samantha_26nov2014.xlsx', 'Disambiguation_Version 1_Xin Hua_entiredata.xlsx', 'Disambiguation_Version 2o_Maximus.xlsx', 'Disambiguation_Version 2o_theresa.xlsx', 'Disambiguation_Version 2t_Cheng Ai.xlsx', 'Disambiguation_Version 2_Summer_entiredata.xlsx', 'Disambiguation_Version 2_Tricia.xlsx', 'Disambiguation_Version 3_Emily_entiredataset.xlsx', 'test']

['Disambiguation_Version 1_Samantha_26nov2014.xlsx', 'Disambiguation_Version 1_Xin Hua_entiredata.xlsx', 'Disambiguation_Version 2t_Cheng Ai.xlsx']
```

It gives me two arrays instead of one, and thus my files are processed twice.

Please help with some inputs as to where I'm going wrong.

Comment: we write in capital letters when we want to threat someone

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems:

1. You are printing the list in each loop iteration.
2. You are calling the `pj.py` file in each loop iteration.
3. You are not passing the full path to the file, just the file name.
4. You have named the file `dir.py`, and this is the name of a built-in function.

To start off with, you should use glob, and create a method in your file that lists the directories, then call this method in your other program instead of using `execfile`:

In one file, lets call it `list_excel.py`, you can have some code like this:

```
import glob
import os

def get_excel_files(directory=None):
    for filename in glob.iglob(os.path.join(directory, '*.xls?')):
        yield filename
```

In `pj.py`, you can import this function (make sure `list_excel.py` and `pj.py` are in the same directory):

```
from list_excel import get_excel_files

root = 'C:/Users/Desktop/Files/test'

for file_location in get_excel_files(root):
    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_location)
```

Comment: Burhan thanks for the answer. The reason I'm executing the files inside the first program is because I do not want to make any changes in the second program. Is it possible to keep the programs as it is and only change the first program where I'm calling the excel files. There are 10 files. Each file has to be manipulated. I want to pass the file name as a variable to the pj.py program which does all the manipulation. Kindly advise.

Comment: It depends entirely on how the `pj.py` is expecting the file arguments. If it is expecting them from the standard input, then you can just call it with the full path of the excel sheet as an argument. You can also do other acrobatics like importing the module and then masking the names; but as you have access to the source; simply modifying `pj.py` would be the easiest solution.